# Moto Droid - Screen Going Crazy / SD Card Contents

Tags: motorola-droid, sd-card, screen, storage

So about an hour ago I was texting and noticed that when I would try to hit certain letters using the on-screen keyboard that it would think I pressed the keys to the left or right of a certain area.  It seemed like a deadspot to me and already I was disappointed but it wasn't a giant issue as I could just use the hardware keyboard til I got it fixed.  Now, however, after ~1 minute of being booted up, the screen just starts going crazy, loading random applications, zooming in on stuff, flickering left and right like I was swiping it.  I was wondering if anyone had any experience as to what can cause this (other than hardware failure) and if you think doing a factory reset will help at all (assuming I can get through the options fast enough before the screen goes nuts).

Also, before trying a factory reset, I was wondering what all is stored on the SD card by default.  I'm not really worried about apps (I'll just re-download them) or contacts (synced with Google I believe), but more media (pictures / videos [both that I took and downloaded] / music).  Now common sense would suggest that media items would all be stored on the SD card, but I know from experience not to assume things like this.  If you could fill me in it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Very strange but something very similar started happening on my Moto Droid 1 close to the same time (11:47 EST).  Rebooting didn't seem to do anything, but I pulled the battery and then when I started it up things were back to normal.  I don't see how they could be related but it is a strange coincidence.

Comment: This just recently started happening to me as well (OG DROID, first run from the initial release in Nov. 2009). I'm running CyanogenMod with the freeform pattern lock; because of this, I noticed that the screen seems to think something is swiping back and forth along a line that matches up with the top edge of the hardware keyboard when it's slid out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictures, videos, downloads, and music are all stored on the SD card by default. You can get at them by popping your SD card into any card reader. (probably have to get an adapter)

App settings are stored on the phone. But if those apps support google's backup service those settings will be restored on your new phone.

Comment: Thanks.  App settings I can fiddle with as need be to get them right, I'm not terribly worried about that.  My major concern was losing all the pictures and stuff I took.

Answer (score 0):

I decided "F it" and pulled the SD card and did a factory reset.  The problem still persists so it is most definitely a hardware issue.  I guess I'll have to take it in :/.

Comment: Yep, definitely hardware.  Too bad :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a Droid 1. Screen got very jittery when I used a non-OEM charging cable, unless I held the back of the phone in a certain way. Also noticed this when running Cyanogen ver 6.0 .
Went back to the stock ROM. Finally starting doing it again. I ended up sending it back and getting a warranty replacement. Factory reset did not fix it. Warranty replacement works fine.